# Having an akka Source.queue and wait for jobs

Tags: playframework, akka

I need a simple mechanism where 'jobs' are put into e.g a BlockingQueue and that these are processed with a trottle of e.g. 5 a second.

I was hoping to use akka Source.queue, but don't seem to grasp how to set this up so the system keeps working when the queue is empty (so a continual watch) as it just stops (and that is what the example work in the akka documentation). When encountering it previously I ended up creating my own custom Thread but in this case I need parallel processing.

What would be the pattern to create e.g. 'continuous' actor monitoring a queue?
I am using Java and the Play! Framework.

[EDIT]: Added my code which seems to work now, but seems clumsy. To explain, a request to contact a device with updated data comes into the Actor. The Actor sees if there is already on in the 'requestQeueu' (when there is a change on the system, multiple update request come at the same time). If not, add it, and then schedule a connection (after a short interval to allow multiple changes to be included in the one communication). The connection is then put in the Source.queue.

```
private static final HashMap<Long, String> requestQueue = new HashMap<>();
private static final HashMap<Long, Date> lastDeviceConnection = new HashMap<>();

private final SourceQueueWithComplete<Device> sourceQueue;

private static final int timeBetweenConnectionsToDevice = 750;
private static final int timeToWaitBeforeConnecting = 250;

 @Inject
    ContactServer(ActorSystem system) {
        this.system = system;

        int bufferSize = 10;
        int elementsToProcess = 5;

        sourceQueue =
            Source.<Device>queue(bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure())
                .throttle(elementsToProcess, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map(device -> {
                    String fromServer = null;
                    try {
                        String thisJson = requestQueue.get(device.getId());
                        requestQueue.remove(device.getId());
                        device.refresh();


                        Socket serviceSocket = new Socket(device.getIpAddress(), 7780);
                        
                        <!-- do communication -->

                        out.close();
                        in.close();
                        serviceSocket.close();

                        String data = encoding.decrypt(fromServer);

                        <!-- do processing -->
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.info("Problem contacting the device (server initiative): " + device.getName(), e);
                        if (fromServer != null)
                            logger.warn("The return data of the last error was: " + fromServer);
                    }
                    return device;
                })
                .to(Sink.foreach(x -> logger.debug("Processed: " + x)))
                .run(system);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(Map.Entry.class, message -> {
                    final Device device = ((Map.Entry<Device, String>) message).getKey();
                    final String actionJson = ((Map.Entry<Device, String>) message).getValue();
                    try {

                        if (requestQueue.containsKey(device.getId())) {
                            if (actionJson != null && requestQueue.get(device.getId()) != null) {
                                requestQueue.put(device.getId(), requestQueue.get(device.getId()) + "," + actionJson);
                            } else if (actionJson != null) {
                                requestQueue.put(device.getId(), actionJson);
                            } else {
                                return;
                            }
                        } else {
                            requestQueue.put(device.getId(), actionJson);
                        }

                        long waitTime = timeToWaitBeforeConnecting;
                        if ((lastDeviceConnection.containsKey(device.getId()) && lastDeviceConnection.get(device.getId()).after(new Date(new Date().getTime() - timeBetweenConnectionsToDevice)))) {
                            long timeBeforeNextDeviceConnection = new Date().getTime() - lastDeviceConnection.get(device.getId()).getTime() - timeBetweenConnectionsToDevice;

                            if(timeBeforeNextDeviceConnection > waitTime) waitTime = timeBeforeNextDeviceConnection;
                        }

                        system.scheduler().scheduleOnce(scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.create(waitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), () -> {
                            sourceQueue.offer(device);
                        },context().dispatcher());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.info("Exception scheduling the device connection (server initiative): " + device.getName(), e);
                    } finally {
                        context().stop(self());
                    }
                }).build();
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're trying to do. So presumably you have a stream starting with `Source.queue` then if there's nothing in the queue the stream has nothing to process so it doesn't really stop, it just sits idle waiting for items on the queue.... Perhaps if you shared a bit of code it would be clearer what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks artier, I will when I get a chance. I tried it before, but don't have the code handy. The processing would happen while there were items in the queue, but as soon the queue was empty the flow stopped and would not start with new items. So if it is intended to work that way I did something wrong.

Comment: The documentation is very detailed about interacting with `Source.queue` perhaps you'll find it useful: [Source.queue](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#queue[T](bufferSize:Int,overflowStrategy:akka.stream.OverflowStrategy):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.stream.scaladsl.SourceQueueWithComplete[T]])

Comment: Please share what will be the sink for result.

Comment: I added the current code which seems to kind-of-work after reading the documentation again. However, I think it seems a clumsy way of doing what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

So, I am not sure I fully understand your requirements. Especially around timing as you are using two mechanisms:

1. using scheduling
2. using throttling on the queue

I also see how you're aggregating actions for particular deviceId in a `HashMap`. If the number of possible deviceIds is "reasonable" then I think you can leverage Akka Streams Api to do those things for you.

I am assuming following:

1. You don't want to process more than 5 messages per second
2. You don't want to connect to perform actions for particular device more often than once per second.
3. You want to aggregate actions for the same device as in your code snipped at the beginning of the handler.
4. All possible device ids are in order of thousands as opposed to millions (see `groupBy` documentation).

```java
sourceQueue =
      Source.<Map.Entry<Device, String>>queue(bufferSize,
                                              OverflowStrategy.backpressure())
        .throttle(elementsToProcess, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .groupBy(1000, Map.Entry::getKey) //max 1000 devices
        .conflate(
          (aggregate, d) ->
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(d.getKey(),
                                          aggregate.getValue() +
                                          "," + d.getValue()))
        .throttle(1, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .map(deviceEntry -> {
          //here goes the connection part, but DON'T use blocking IO, 
          //use separate threadpool with mapAsync instead
          ...
        })
        .async()
        .mergeSubstreams()
        .to(Sink.foreach(x -> logger.debug("Processed: " + x)))
        .run(system);
```

Then in your recieve you only call `offer` on the queue. You also should check the result of the `offer()` call to check if you were successful or if you got backpressured in which case you need to either back off or drop the item or buffer it.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like what I like to do. I will pop this in in the next few days when I have to time to monitor the results. Just a possible slight difference is that I don't want to do more then 5 contacts(to different devices) in a second and do not want to contact the same device twice in lets say a second. This is because in the processing, one device can have 5-10 notifications of a change, and I want to sent them all at the same time if that makes sense. So the amount of messages being accepted does not need to be throttled per se, but what is fed through does.